# What describes a person who is extremely carefree to the point of risking their life?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes someone who is extremely carefree to the point of risking their lives. The person is not even bad or annoying; in fact, they are vibrant & outgoing. Except they don't extremely carefree to the point of risking their lives. I was thinking of "extremely carefree" or even "unhinged".

For example,

> That girl who got stabbed at the club was______; She was outgoing but extremely carefree to a scary point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**reckless** | ˈrekləs |
adjective
(of a person or their actions) without thinking or caring about the consequences of an action: *reckless driving.*

Answer (score 0):

**Daredevil** is used to describe a person who enjoys taking dangerous risks

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/daredevil)